# Google App Engine instead of shared hosting for low traffic sites?

Tags: shared-hosting, google-app-engine

I have a non-profit Drupal site which attracts very few visitors (like 50 per day) and has about 500MB worth of data. 
I'm wondering roughly how much should I pay to GAE to host such site?

Currently I pay and annul $40 fee to my shared hosting. 
I've looked at the Google's price calculator but could not figure out how to calculate as I'm unfamiliar with the cloud jargon.